# How to check if assign a string to two variable is by reference or by value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, memory

How to know if I assign a value into two variable, is it copied or is it referenced? for example:

```
var obj = {};
var y;
var x = obj.bla = y = 'a very very long text...' // about 10 MB
```

Is `x`, `obj.bla` and `y` referencing the same memory location, or that string is copied by value?

Comment: Primitives are immutable, so I don't think this is a useful distinction. (You can think of variables with the same string as sharing a reference to a common immutable string (*string interning*), or you can think of it as copying by value and that the equality operation tests for identical string values.) Are you interested in engine internals? If so, specify which engine you're interested in.

Comment: it's for `v8`, `SpiderMonkey` and `JavaScriptCore`

Comment: I would think it's vendor specific how they solve it internally, as long as the variables all contain the same primitive immutable string, it's up to spec, and for our use it doesn't matter how the engine solves the references to memory.

Comment: ah ok then, I just hope my app won't go out of memory..

Answer (score 3):

Strings are passed by value (everything is, really), there are no pointers, and where it is in memory doesn't matter.

Comment: Passing and assigning are 2 different things tough e.g in java you pass by value-refeference and you assign references (with objects which strings are). So you are maybe right, Id just encourge you to explain in a little more detail beacuse the question is about passing

Comment: sorry I did not get you when you say **everything is**. what about this `var a = new Date() ; var b = a`. I hope now a and b are referencing the same object, b is just another variable that points to same object created earlier.

Comment: @for3st - strings aren't objects, they are primitives, and even objects are passed by value, or more correctly a copy, not by reference.

Comment: @codehx: He means that the *reference to the object* is passed by value. Both `a` and `b` hold a reference value (to the same object). `b` does not reference `a` (as it would when "passed by reference", where assigning to `b` changes `a`)

Comment: @adeneo I talked about Java, not JS just as example. But again the question is about assigning. As codehx wrote b = a propably assigns the reference, but things maybe different with primitives. The things you argue here could be used to improve the answer

Comment: Java != JavaScript, the latter has no pass-by-reference, and really no references, just copies of references.

Comment: @for3st - and when you assign a string to a variable, and then assign that variable to another variable, you're passing the content of the first variable to the other variable, so it really is passing.

Comment: @adeneo you are right when the vars are string but in the example I poided above ^ if you modify a you will be modifying b too. little confused

Comment: @codehx - indeed, you will modify both if the value is non-primitive, and it is confusing, but it's still passing by value, not by a true reference like java or C++ would etc.

Comment: @adeneo: I'm pretty sure Java is pass by value (sharing) as well.

Comment: @codehx: You are making the common(!) mistake to equate "pass-by-reference" with object references. I recommend to read http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy. Pass by reference means you can do this: `var a = 42; var b = a; a = 21;` and `b` would have the value 21. However, I hope you agree that this not possible in JS, no matter which value `a` has (object or primitive).

Comment: @FelixKling - had to look that up, as my Java-fu is non-existent, but you're right, Java is always pass by value.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you figure out. Basically objects and arrays are referenced otherwise variables are passed as values and basically copied.

```
(function()
{
    var a = {x:1,y:2};
    var b = 15;
    SubFunc(a,b);
    console.log("new"+a.x);
    console.log("new"+b);  
})();

function SubFunc(a,b)
{
    a.x += 2;
    b += 2;
    console.log(a.x);
    console.log(b);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Primitives are immutable, so of course trying to mutate them will create a new value. All you have shown is how objects are stored in variables (as reference). You haven't shown whether, when having `foo = bar = 42`, the actual data is duplicated (same value in two different memory locations).

Comment: What I tried to prove is the same thing what you are saying primitives are immutable and objects are referenced. As for your question:
var foo;
var bar;
foo = bar = 24;
foo++;
console.log(foo);//Will output 25
console.log(bar);//Will output 24
This shows that the data was duplicated in different memory location.I hope I am clear.

Comment: Again, this doesn't show that the data is duplicated, only that primitives are immutable. `foo++` creates a new value and stores it in `foo`. It tells you as much about the internals as doing `foo = 42` instead.